# Using MVC style, where is the best place to put SQL functionality?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, programming-practices, mvc

I am wondering about best practices here.

MVC (Model - View - Controller) patterns involve separating components of your program that model the data, manipulate those models, and display those results to the user (usually through the UI) in some way.

What about a function that takes the model data and inserts it into a database? For example I have an object called a GameBoard, and I also want the ability to insert the state of this board into the SQL database for storage / historical purposes. I have a class that holds all my query functions.

But where would I call these functions from? Would this sort of functionality make the most sense to make it as a method of GameBoard? Or should it be part of the controller classes?

For example, I've got a GameBoard class and an SQLDatasource/SQLHelper class (which I call the "models"). The SQL classes have methods that take care of the queries and such. In Android, there are also Activity classes where all the "events" take place (I call these the "controllers"). The "view" takes place via code that binds the Activity to some XML. That being said, I normally instantiate the GameBoards in the Activity classes, and right now I also call the query functions from these same classes that accept a GameBoard as an argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should SQL/DB Queries be encapsulated in a software system?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/142596/where-should-sql-db-queries-be-encapsulated-in-a-software-system)

Comment: @gnat I am not asking where to put the queries. I have all the queries in one class. I am asking where I'd call those query functions from.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134820/in-an-mvc-system-where-should-the-database-persistence-code-sit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A typical (but simplified) MVC architecture looks like this:

```
Database <-->  Logic Layer <--> Controller <--> View
```

Your Logic Layer contains the functions that you would call to perform your game-related activities.  The purpose of the Logic Layer is to translate your game-related functions into database operations.

Comment: I always sort of considered the Controller and Logic Layer to be the same. Is this wrong?

Comment: The Logic Layer is part of your **Model** (the M in MVC). Think of the controller as a switch-yard.  It accepts your requests, and shunts them to methods that have primary responsibility for performing your game functions.

Comment: Maybe I should be more explicit. For example, I've got a GameBoard class and an SQLDatasource/SQLHelper class (which I call the "models"). The SQL classes have methods that take care of the queries and such. In Android, there are also Activity classes where all the "events" take place (I call these the "controllers"). The "view" takes place via code that binds the Activity to some XML. That being said, I normally instantiate the GameBoards in the Activity classes, and right now I also call the query functions from these same classes. Is all of this a correct understanding?

Comment: This is all happening inside your phone?

Comment: I'm making an Android app, which uses Java, but yes

Comment: Then I would defer to the common architecture that is typically used in phones for this sort of thing.  I don't think that's MVC, but I could be wrong.  MVC seems like a bit overkill.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2925054

Answer (score 1):

A good approach is the [DAO pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).

Use a DAO class per entity to handle any SQL related functionality.